# Calling a fabric nested method with fewer hosts in decorator

Tags: python, decorator, fabric

I have

```
@roles('production')
def submethod():
    run('service restart')


@roles('all')
def deploy():
    put('somefile.conf')
    submethod()
```

I call deploy(), but then all services are restarted, in all hosts, what is the best way to get this done? It seems the @roles('production') is not working...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a task from another task, you should use [execute](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/core/tasks.html#fabric.tasks.execute):

```
def submethod():
    run('service restart')


@roles('all')
def deploy():
    put('somefile.conf')
    execute(submethod, roles=['production'])
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This way 'service restart' is executed in the right host, but 20 times, the same times as len(@roles('all'))

Comment: I can use @runs_once, but then It executes once in production (as I want) but may in the iteration when I put somefile.conf in other host. I mean it restarts the service before the file is actually copied in production.